# SkImageDecoder:factory returned null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am trying to get the image from sdcard to display it in an imageview in android. Its showing error as SkImageDecoder:factory returned null in android emulator2.2. Here is my code to retrieve image from SDcard to imageview in android.

```
File imgFile = new File("/sdcard/wm.png");
if (imgFile.exists()) {
     Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
     ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Please resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you checked this on real device?

Comment: ya..i checked..but it showing the same error.

Comment: @RajeshkumarThangavel Your code is working fine.

Comment: no @DipakKeshariya.Im getting SkImageDecoder:factory returned null when im runnin this code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) or  [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) instead of hard coding the path of the sd card (i.e `"/sdcard/wm.png"`).